# How to add function for QT-Designer Push Button

Tags: python, pyqt5, qt-designer

I am working on QT Designer to build GUI App. I want to ask how add command for push button.
For example I want to apply this action :

```
self.NfmtLoginButton.clicked.connect(lambda: SecondScript.printme(self.NfmtPasswordEntry.text()))
```

Is it possible through the QT Designer. to be permanently saved. and no need to add all the commands again when generating new python script file from UI file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it's not possible, but that should not be a problem, as the files generated using `pyuic` should never, **ever** be modified (the warning in those files is not to be undertaken).

Those files should *always* be left unmodified and only updated again with pyuic, as they are **only** meant to be *imported* in the actual program file, as explained in the official guidelines about [using Designer](https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt5/designer.html) (the "multiple inheritance approach is generally the most suggested).